# Is there a keyboard shortcuts for the fixed size marquee in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts, marquee-tool

I use the rectangular marquee tool a lot, specially the fixed size option, is there a shortcut to swap the width and height of it? Also is there a shortcut to apply new dimensions?

Comment: I don't think there is a shortcut. It also seems you can't record that as an Action and the Scripting Listener plugin doesn't record it, which is immediately a relatively big hurdle, if not a dead-end. There are things scripting listener doesn't record, that are still scriptable... but what that usually means is it requires writing custom Action Manager code, which is notoriously difficult to work with and that part of scripting is practically undocumented. Though there are some tools made by various people that help working with Action Manager...

Comment: Thank you, I will try with scripting an action and if it is done by me I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no shortcut, but you **can** create a **Tool preset** with specific options set.

- Open the **Tool Presets Panel** (`View > Tool Presets`)
- Select the Marquee Tool
- Set the options for the Marquee Tool how you want them
- Click the **New** button on the bottom of the Tool Presets panel, you'll be asked to give the preset a name.

From that point forward, you can merely click the preset and the tool/options you set will be selected.

You can also use the Preset menu in the Control bar, across the top of the screen, to select the preset:

[image]

While not a shortcut, this does provide a one-click solution to commonly used settings for a tool.

Comment: A small addition: the presets then can be called via Actions or Scripts making it possible to assign those to F-keys or any allowed Photoshop key combination respectively.

Comment: This seems somewhat related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/113280/2332 — Though my assumption was that the width and height are not always the same, in which case making a preset wouldn't really help... @SergeyKritskiy did post an answer with Action Manager code that fetches the current eyedropper setting, which seems slightly more relevant if that is the case. Obviously not a full-on solution, but a glimpse into that world of nightmares.